# Store seconds in the database - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seconds

I have a `Timekeeper` model in my app. It keeps track of started_at time and finished_at time. I want to take the difference between these two `datetimes` and pull out the seconds and store that value in the database as an integer. Here is what I'm currently working with.

Method:

```
((timekeeper.started_at - Time.current) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

This returns a value that looks like this : `-2336036`

The two times above are only 12 seconds apart and I get that value. I'm not sure what it is saying.

The takeaway from my question is: `How can I store seconds in the database, between two datetimes that looks similar to what I'm doing currently?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the difference between the 2 times you just need to do the subtraction as the difference is returned in seconds.

```
time.started_at - Time.current
```

if you dont want the fraction of a second

```
(time.started_at - Time.current).to_i
```

and the absolute value

```
((time.started_at - Time.current).to_i).abs
```

try the above in a rails console